# Excel textbox formated text to Htmlbody convert

Tags: vba, excel

I need to send text from Excel textbox with HTMLBODY. So when i send it as

```
.HTMLBody = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("info").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
```

Email comes without formating.

So how to convert textbox to Html source? Or how to get data from html file to `.HTMLBody`?

Comment: I am unaware of a library in Excel that converts formatted text to HTML. Yet, I do know that Word allows you to SaveAs html. But the resulting HTML is extremely bulky and full of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ron de Bruin's website has some great stuff on sending HTML emails. Look on [this page](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) for the `RangetoHTML` function.